# TableView Cell background on edit not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with a transparent background, and a content offset to allow part of a background image to be visible at the top of the first cell. The content offset is set with: `accordianTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)`

As shown in the following image, the green highlighted rectangle is the first cell of the tableview, which has a solid white background. The cell is in edit mode, but there is a transparent section when the cell is dragged to the right, where the background image is visible through the cell even though it has a white background...

I cannot have the background of the table view solid white, since this would cause the background image to be totally invisible through the table view.

How can I make the entire cell background always white, even when dragged to the right while editing?

[image: IOS TableView Cell]

Comment: if you want to show image on top of the tableView, why not use the `tableView.tableHeaderView`? If you want it to stick to the top of the view with the cells, then add it to first section as section view

Comment: That's not the effect I'm trying to achieve. The image is being animated, and therefore cannot be part of the tableview.

Comment: Why it cant be a part of the tableView? can you explain more the image get animated?

Comment: Because I need to move the image around myself, not managed through the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around the issue by adding an empty UIView behind the tableview, and changing its position to always be behind the tableview - providing a background color for the cells while in edit mode.